# How to make gradiants look smooth on older / cheap Androids like HTC Magic?

Tags: android, android-layout

It seems their displays dont have enough colors. Right?

Can I do smth. about it? What shall I tell my designer?

Comment: I am not able to test the given answer(s) anymore. Please suggest if I should mark an answer done, if you have tested it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to enable dithering. If you're using a GradientDrawable, use `setDither(true)`.

Comment: The background drawable of my Buttons are PNG files with gradiants. Does your answer work for me in this case, like myButton.setDither(true)?

Comment: Well, if you're using an image, then your artist will need to add the dithering into the PNG.

Comment: Hey, I spoke to soon, the base `Drawable` class also has a `setDither`. That may do the trick already.